Populating slider carousel with server-fetched AssetImages paths
I have flutter code for page that display user Cards with slider carousel. It works perfectly with predefined card images paths as follows:
List<String> cardImages = [
'assets/GameCard_01.png',
'assets/GameCard_02.png'
];
This then populated the carousel container here:
                     return child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage(cardImages[index]),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

However now I want to display the cards specific to the current user.
I have this js services file code :
static async getCarddata(userId) {
    try {
        const cardData = await CardModel.find({ userId }, { cardImage: 1, _id: 0 });
        return cardData;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}

It returns, based on the given current user's userId, every associated card's image path (to assets folder in flutter project) like this for example:
{
    "status": true,
    "success": [
        {
            "cardImage": "assets/GameCard_01.png" 
        },
        {
           "cardImage": "assets/GameCard_02.png" 
        },
    ]
}

All what I have already tried has failed so i need assistance.
Page code: ( I have switched from slide carousel to PageView for test purposes:
class CardsDisplayPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String token;

  const CardsDisplayPage({Key? key, required this.token}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CardsDisplayPageState createState() => _CardsDisplayPageState();
}

class _CardsDisplayPageState extends State<CardsDisplayPage> {
  List<String> cardImages = [];

  int _currentPage = 0;
  late PageController _pageController;
  late String phoneNumber;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    _pageController.addListener(_pageListener);
    fetchCardImages();
  }

  void _pageListener() {
    setState(() {
      _currentPage = _pageController.page!.toInt() % cardImages.length;
    });
  }

  void fetchCardImages() async {
    try {
      // Here I decode the token to extract user ID
      final decodedToken = jsonDecode(widget.token);
      final userId = decodedToken['userId'];

      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(getUserCardList),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ${widget.token}',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
          'userId': userId,
        }),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<dynamic> responseData = jsonDecode(response.body)['success'];
        setState(() {
          cardImages =
              responseData.map((card) => card['cardImage'] as String).toList();
        });
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load card images');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching card images: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
                ),
                topAppBar(token: widget.token),
                SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 255.0,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      PageView.builder(
                        controller: _pageController,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage(
                                    cardImages[index % cardImages.length],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 10.0,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: List.generate(
                        cardImages.length,
                        (index) => _buildDot(index),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      endDrawer: const menu(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDot(int index) {
    return Container(
      width: 7.5,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: _currentPage == index
            ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 20, 120, 202)
            : Color.fromARGB(255, 223, 223, 223),
      ),
    );
  }
}


So you mean to say, you are requesting to server and getting image url from the api right? In that case just use Dio or http package, request to the server, get the img url and anything and use it, no need to run js code in flutter app

I did use http and tried exactly that but nothing seem to work:
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
List responseData = jsonDecode(response.body)['success'];
setState(() {
cardImages = responseData.map((card) => card['cardImage']as String).toList();
});
}

Can you please add the code in your question, not in comment and add the complete code like your carousel code, where you are calling the api etc

Of course. It's done

You did not gave itemCount in PageView builder. if you don't give it item count it will conside it as 0. Hence will not show anything. But if prblm stillnot solved after that. Add the response.body you received through api call, so that i can further assist you.
